# Memomy leakage after a function finish in python

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-multiprocessing

I just experienced a memory leakage in python code and discovered that the memory is not released after a function finished. An example of the problem I show below. There is just a class that save a long list of image and a function that print the len of this list.

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import psutil
import os
import cv2
import gc

src_path = Path('/home/ben/blob/1568204445571/')

path_list1 = list(src_path.iterdir())[:1000]
path_list2 = list(src_path.iterdir())[1000:2000]


class ListImg:
    def __init__(self, list_img_path):
        self.img_ls = [cv2.imread(str(img_path/'_.ppm')) for img_path in list_img_path]
def get_len_img_list(list_img_path):
    List = ListImg(list_img_path)
    _len = len(List.img_ls)
    print(_len)

%memit
for path_list in [path_list1, path_list2]:
    get_len_img_list(path_list)
    %memit
```

[Picture - Memory leakage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdmMF.png)

Even when I delete all the variable related, the memory usage is still high

I found a way that overcome this problem is by running the function in a process.

```
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
%memit
for path_list in [path_list1, path_list2]:
    print(process.memory_info().rss) 
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_len_img_list, args=(path_list,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    %memit
```

[Picture - Solve memory leakage with process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7KNe.png)

The problem is not related to jupyter because when I ran it in pure python code, the memory shown is the same.

[Picture - Memory graph without process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Xmy.png)

[Picture - Memory graph with process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOTfn.png)

Do we have an explanation of that and what is the proper way you used when facing the memory leakage ?

Thank you

Comment: Memory usage going up is not necessarily a leak.

Comment: Sure. But I think after the function finished the memory should go down right ? In this case, it is still there and accumulate if I do something else, then lead to memory overflow

Comment: What metric, specifically are you using for memory usage?